# Divide a number into equal parts and store their cumulative sum

Tags: php, math

Simple question, how do I get every option when dividing a number? For example:

- `24 by 6` returns `6, 12, 18, 24`
- `24 by 4` returns `4, 8, 12, 16, 20, 24`
- `24 by 5` returns `false`

I've got a number in my database, for example 2, and my counter, for example 14. That means every time my counter hits the second number, I want to fire my event. So I thought, if I have the solutions 2, 4, 6, etc, and my counter is equal to one of the solutions, I can fire my event.

Comment: Could you explain a little bit more? I am missing question honestly... :(

Comment: @true Check back in a minute, i'll add some information.

Comment: Which part do you have a problem with? What have you tried?

Comment: @gordon: I think *quotient* is misleading here. The quotient of `24 by 6` is `4`. This is somehow related to quotient sets, but in any case, the results would be equivalence classes.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It's rather trivial to make.

```
<?php

/**
 * @param int $number  The beginning number
 * @param int $divider The number dividing by
 *
 * @return array
 * @throws Exception   In case $number is not divisible by $divider
 */
function get_number_sequence($number, $divider) {
    //In case $number is not divisible by $divider, throw an Exception.
    if ($number % $divider !== 0) {
        throw new Exception("$number is not divisible by $divider");
    }
    //Return an array from $divider to $number in steps of $divider.
    $result = range($divider, $number, $divider);
    return $result;
}

/*
 * Testing begins
 */

try {
    echo "<pre>";
    echo implode(", ", get_number_sequence(24, 4)) . PHP_EOL;
    echo implode(", ", get_number_sequence(24, 6)) . PHP_EOL;
    echo implode(", ", get_number_sequence(24, 5)) . PHP_EOL;
    echo "</pre>";
}
catch (Exception $e) {
    echo "Invalid: " . $e->getMessage();
}
```

### Some Points

- Don't return false if something exceptional happens, use an `Exception` as shown in the example.
- Use the modulus operator to determine if the number is divisible or not.
- Return an array, not a string. It's easier to work with.

Comment: +1 for clever use of `range`. I dont think you need to throw an Exception though but rather return an empty array. Whole thing can be as simple as `return $number % $base === 0 ? range($base, $number, $base) : array();`

Comment: @Gordon: Meh, I think it's an exceptional case, so an exception should be thrown. An empty array is another option.

Answer (score 1):

should be easy 
do a modulus on X by Y . If 0 then do a division on X by Y. create a loop which will run from 1 to (division on X by Y) and output Y multiplied by the loop counter

Comment: There's actually no need for a loop. use `range()`.

Answer (score 1):

```
function findQuotients($number, $divider)
{
    $arr = array();

    if($number % $divider != 0)
    {
        //return "false";        
    }
    else 
    {
        $loop = $number / $divider;
        //$output="";
        for($i = 1; $i <= $loop; $i++)
        {
            //$output .= $i * $divider. " ";
            array_push($arr, $i * $divider);
        }           
    }
    return $arr;
}

echo print_r(findQuotients(24, 6));
echo print_r(findQuotients(24, 4));
echo print_r(findQuotients(24, 5));
```

Comment: This won't return it will echo.

Comment: @Truth: I've update my code. Now you can remove the -1 . Thanks :)

Comment: While I still don't like the fact you're returning strings, your answer isn't as horrible. -1 removed :)

Answer (score 1):

```
function steps($target,$step) {
    if (($target % $step) != 0)
        return FALSE;
    $steps = range($step,$target,$step);
    return $steps;
}

$target = 24;
for ($step = 2; $step < 13; ++$step) {
    echo '$step = ',$step,PHP_EOL;
    $steps = steps($target,$step);
    var_dump($steps);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
$number = 24;
$divider = 6;
if($number % $divider != 0 )
{ 
    return false;
}
$div = $number / $divider;

for($i = 1; $i <= $div; $i++)
{
    echo $i*$divider;
}
```

Comment: This won't return, it will echo.

Answer (score 0):

The following snippet will do the trick. It's a simple loop to iterate until `$num` is <= 0. `$num` will be subtracted by the divider and each turn the next multiple of `$div` will be stored as a *"divider step"*.

```
$num = 24;
$div = 4;

if ($num % $div != 0) {
    exit('invalid');
}

$divider = array();
for ($i = 1; $num > 0; $i++) {
    $divider[] = ($i * $div);
    $num -= $div;
}

echo 'in: ' . $num . '<br />';
echo 'div: ' . $div . '<br />';
echo '<pre>';
print_r($divider);
exit;
```

Comment: This won't return it will echo.

Comment: Don't be that strange, it's just an example.

Comment: As a beginner author, I can't do anything with that example. At least explain how to minimally adapt it to needs other than displaying!

Answer (score 0):

based on your description you want to multiply a number and then on a given result you want to white a function:

```
$num = 6;
$counter = 2;
$solution = 24;
while ($num * $counter) {
    $result= $num * $counter;
    if ($result = $solution) {
        echo $result;
        // here would go your event
        break;
    }
}
```

Comment: This won't return it will echo.

Comment: I used echo, you can use return or any thing you need